# Dynamically filtering an array of objects with n filter criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array of objects (data), and I need to filter this array based on filter criteria (criteria) where each criteria can have multiple values.

```
var data = [
  { ID: 1, Name: "John", Color: "Blue", Location: "Up" },
  { ID: 2, Name: "Pauline", Color: "Green", Location: "Up" },
  { ID: 3, Name: "Ahmed", Color: "Orange", Location: "Left" },
  { ID: 4, Name: "Diego", Color: "Pink", Location: "Up" },
  { ID: 5, Name: "Maria", Color: "Black", Location: "Down" },
  { ID: 6, Name: "Gus", Color: "Green", Location: "Up" },
  { ID: 7, Name: "Brian", Color: "Pink", Location: "Left" },
  { ID: 8, Name: "Shelley", Color: "Green", Location: "Right" },
  { ID: 9, Name: "Leonardo", Color: "Blue", Location: "Right" },
  { ID: 10, Name: "Big Daddy", Color: "Green", Location: "Down" }
];

var criteria = [
   { Field: "Color", Values: ["Green"] },
   { Field: "Location", Values: ["Up", "Down"] }
];
```

I need an array of object (filtered) in such a way that
1. each filter criteria is treated as "AND"
2. multiple filter values in a filter field are treated as "OR". So this is how the output should be:

```
var filtered = [
      { ID: 2, Name: "Pauline", Color: "Green", Location: "Up" },
      { ID: 6, Name: "Gus", Color: "Green", Location: "Up" },  
      { ID: 10, Name: "Big Daddy", Color: "Green", Location: "Down" }  
    ];
```

Comment: That's very nice, but we're not a code writing service, so learn [ask]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! 
Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.every` for AND condition and `array.indexOf` for OR condition.

Note, `indexOf` is case sensitive. If you want make it case insensitive, you can transform both values to lower case and compare

```js
var data = [
  { ID: 1, Name: "John", Color: "Blue", Location: "Up" },
  { ID: 2, Name: "Pauline", Color: "Green", Location: "Up" },
  { ID: 3, Name: "Ahmed", Color: "Orange", Location: "Left" },
  { ID: 4, Name: "Diego", Color: "Pink", Location: "Up" },
  { ID: 5, Name: "Maria", Color: "Black", Location: "Down" },
  { ID: 6, Name: "Gus", Color: "Green", Location: "Up" },
  { ID: 7, Name: "Brian", Color: "Pink", Location: "Left" },
  { ID: 8, Name: "Shelley", Color: "Green", Location: "Right" },
  { ID: 9, Name: "Leonardo", Color: "Blue", Location: "Right" },
  { ID: 10, Name: "Big Daddy", Color: "Green", Location: "Down" },
  { ID: 11, Name: "Dummy", Color: ["Green", "Orange"], Location: "Down" }
];

var criteria = [
   { Field: "Color", Values: ["Green"] },
   { Field: "Location", Values: ["Up", "Down"] }
];

var result = data.filter(function(obj){
  return criteria.every(function(c){
    var value = obj[c.Field];
    if(typeof value === 'object') {
      return Object.keys(value).some(function(key){
        return c.Values.indexOf(value[key]) > -1
      })
    }
    else
      return c.Values.indexOf(value) > -1
  })
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I used exactly the same logic, but instead did a negative some. You provided a more elegant answer

Comment: Yup I saw your answer. Just a pointer, these functions are part of functional programming and are meant to make it easy to read the code. `!some` will take time to understand. Its *filtering data where all criteria are met* vs *filtering data where either one criteria is not met*. Both will do the job but you should choose the one that is more easy to read and relate.

Comment: I agree! And that is why your answer is more elegant than mine.

Comment: @Rajesh . Thanks for your answer. But if one of the let's say one of the fields of the data is an array { ID: 3, Name: "Ahmed", Color: ["Orange", "Green"], Location: "Left" }, then how will I deal with filtering?

Comment: @sonal in the color in criteria is `orange`, then should this object be considered as valid?

Comment: @Rajesh If you see the filtercriteria, then you will notice that Green is one of the colours. So the following
{ ID: 3, Name: "Ahmed", Color: ["Orange", "Green"], Location: "Left" }

should also be a part of the filtered list.

Comment: @Rajesh: Thank you so much. You are a champ. Marking your answer as the correct one.
One more question: Any book or blog which I can start reading to become a master in JS? I am really struggling when I start coding, though I have read the concepts. I have also read The.Principles.Of.Object.Oriented.JavaScript by Nicholas.

Comment: You can start from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript). But you should be ready to get your hands dirty and spend lots of time in doing practical stuff

Answer (score 0):

`Array.some` provides true for any match , and false for every mismatch. We expect a false and then negate it, so that our filter criteria for the original data is correct.

```
filteredData = data.filter(d => 
  !(criteria.some(criterion => 
    criterion.Values.indexOf(d[criterion.Field]) === -1
   ))
)
```

Comment: Also, since you are already using ES6 features, you can also use `array.includes`